# bison rule useless in parser due to conflicts

Tags: bison, rule

I wrote a syntax, but when I compile it, i get a conflict (rule useless in parser due to conflicts). I have no idea how to solve it. I don't understand the problem with "emtpy".

thx, Nine

```
axdef : BBEGIN GKLAMMERLINKS AXDEF GKLAMMERRECHTS def END GKLAMMERLINKS AXDEF GKLAMMERRECHTS
      |
      ;

def : BEZEICHNER Doppelpunkt typ def_next
    ;

def_next : def
         |
         ;

typ : basistyp
    | typ_power
    | FINSET basistyp
    | typ_function
    ;

basistypen : NAT
           | INTEGER
           | REAL
           | BOOL
           | BEZEICHNER
           ;

typ_power : POWER basistyp
          ;

typ_function : BEZEICHNER FUN BEZEICHNER
             | BEZEICHNER FUN POWER BEZEICHNER
             | KLAMMERAUF BEZEICHNER TIMES BEZEICHNER KLAMMERZU fun POWER BEZEICHNER
             ;  

fun : PFUNCTION
    | PINJ
    | PSUR
    | TFUNCTION
    | TINJ
    | SURJ
    | FFUN
    | FINJ
    | BIJ
    ;
```

Comment: basistypen is useless because it is not referenced anywhere in your grammar.  Should basistyp really be basistypen?  I see no conflicts either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your productions `def` and `def_next` look wrong to me.  It can be hard to correctly code the recursive definition of a repeating list of items. I would do it this way:

```
axdef : BBEGIN GKLAMMERLINKS AXDEF GKLAMMERRECHTS defs END GKLAMMERLINKS AXDEF GKLAMMERRECHTS
      |
      ;

defs : def defs
     | def
     ;

def : BEZEICHNER Doppelpunkt typ
    ;
```